# Array of objects to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an the following array:

```
var arr = [{name: "one name"}, {name: "second name"}, {name: "third name"}]
```

My goal is to have array like this:

```
var result = ["one name", "second name", "third name"]
```

I am playing around with something like this, just can't get it right:

```
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  result[arr[i]] = arr[i].NAME;
}
```

What I am misisng?

I am looking how to correct my code and use for loop instead of array map

Comment: What is `arr[i]`?

Comment: You are reinventing map()

Comment: and NAME !== name and you are setting the array's index to a string.

Comment: `var result = arr.map(x=>x.name);`

Comment: @epascarello Or reduce.

Comment: @TimConsolazio reduce requires more code when a simple map is one step.

Comment: Nevertheless...achievable with both depending on your need...less code not always better...etc...really splitting the hair down to the protein there...what are we talking, a few extra chars (really just the accumlator)...and it's still one step...

Comment: Requires you to either push or assign to the array. Yeah it works, so does using a chainsaw to cut a pizza. :) Now if it were filtering out items while mapping, I would use reduce to eliminate a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to fix your code to do it with a `for` loop

```js
var arr = [{name: "one name"}, {name: "second name"}, {name: "third name"}]
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  result[i] = arr[i].name;
}

console.log(result);
```

But using `map` would be more idiomatic javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could map the property values with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = [{name: "one name"}, {name: "second name"}, {name: "third name"}],
    result = array.map(a => a.name);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [***`.map()`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) command to do something like this:

```
const result = arr.map(i => i.name)
```